# GCP PubSub topic push issue

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

i have a nodejs docker image app deployed on gke (gcp). This app is just a message subscriber which waits to be notified. I've created a topic (pubsub). iam trying to add a subscription so my app could be notified. but i didn't manage to do it. I tried to add the ip (domain) in google credentials (APIs & Services/credentials) but the process is really shady. Why verify an app deployed in gcp ?? Is there any way around ? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case someone has the kind of issue someday:
it is a domain name issue. Even if the pod has an ip in gcp, it must be linked to a real and working dns. Otherwise it wont't work.